# Oracle CHAR Comparison Not Working in Function

Tags: oracle

Could someone please explain to me the difference between the below two Oracle queries? I know they look very similar but the first one returns results and the second one does not. My implementation of the function can be seen below as well.

```
--Returns results
SELECT *
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
WHERE ID = CAST(<UserID> AS CHAR(2000)); --ID is defined as CHAR(8) in the DB.

--Does not return results
SELECT *
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
WHERE ID = CAST_TO_CHAR(<UserID>); --ID is defined as CHAR(8) in the DB.

--Function definition
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CAST_TO_CHAR(varToPad IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN CHAR IS returnVal CHAR(2000);
BEGIN
SELECT CAST(varToPad AS CHAR(2000))
INTO returnVal
FROM DUAL;
RETURN returnVal;
END;
/
```

It almost seems to me that the type is not persisting when the value is retrieved from the database. From what I understand from CHAR comparisons in Oracle, it will take the smaller of the two fields and truncate the larger one so that the sizes match (that is why I am casting the second variable to length 2000).

The reason that I need to achieve something like this is because a vendor tool that we are upgrading from DB2 to Oracle defined all of the columns in the Oracle database as CHAR instead of VARCHAR2. They did this to make their legacy code more easily portable to a distributed environment. This is causing big issues in our web applications because compares are now being done against fixed length CHAR fields.

I thought about using TRIM() but these queries will be accessed a lot and I do not want them to do a full table scan each time. I also considered RPAD(, ) but I don't really want to hard code lengths in the application as these may change in the future.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no difference in the two queries. The first one compares a value of 8 characters to a value of 2000 characters. So does the second one. Why on earth are you casting it to `char(2000)` and *not* to `char(8)`? You should really try to convert that to `varchar`.

Comment: Have  you verified that using RPAD or TRIM will result in a full table scan? Also, in your function I believe you can just say `returnVal := CAST(varToPad AS CHAR(2000));` without using a SELECT. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately I am not able to change the column types to VARCHAR as this is how the vendor structured the DB (ridiculous I know). I was trying to cast to a CHAR(2000) so that I would have one generic function to use throughout these changes. Because other columns are CHAR(X) where X varies in size, I figured I would make the size large enough to handle a value from any column in the DB. I have confirmed with our DBAs that TRIM(<Table>) would result in a full table scan. I was trying to not utilize RPAD as I did not want to hard code lengths as they may change

Comment: Can your DBA create function-based indexes using `TRIM()`? If that were accomplished then `TRIM()` would not result in a full table scan.

Comment: That is a very interesting idea. Do you know if this would be possible for every column in a particular table? As mentioned, everything that should be a VARCHAR is unfortunately set up as a CHAR from the vendor. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: It would only be necessary for every column that needed to be indexed - and you would have to be sure to use `TRIM()` in all your `SELECT`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem. It turned out that these are the rules of implicit data conversion. Oracle Database automatically converts a value from one datatype to another when such a conversion makes sense.

If you change your select:

```
SELECT *
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
WHERE CAST(ID as CHAR(2000)) = CAST_TO_CHAR(<UserID>);
```

You will see that's works properly.

And here's another test script showing that the function works correctly:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON --for DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.
DECLARE
    test_string_c CHAR(8);    
    test_string_v VARCHAR2(8);
BEGIN
    --Assign the same value to each string.
    test_string_c := 'string';
    test_string_v := 'string';
    --Test the strings for equality.
    IF test_string_c = CAST_TO_CHAR(test_string_v) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The names are the same');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The names are NOT the same');
    END IF;
END;
/

anonymous block completed
The names are the same
```

Here are some rules govern the direction in which Oracle Database makes implicit datatype conversions:

- During INSERT and UPDATE operations, Oracle converts the value to
  the datatype of the affected column.
- During SELECT FROM operations, Oracle converts the data from the
  column to the type of the target variable.
- When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle
  converts the character data to a numeric value.
- When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle converts
  the character data to DATE.
- When making assignments, Oracle converts the value on the right side
  of the equal sign (=) to the datatype of the target of the assignment
  on the left side.
- When you use a **SQL function** or operator with an argument of a
  datatype other than the one it accepts, **Oracle converts the argument
  to the accepted datatype**.

Complete list of datatype comparison rules you can explore [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm)

Comment: These are the exact details that I was looking for! Is there any way to force the comparison to be a CHAR/CHAR compare without wrapping the ID table in a CAST as well? Do you know if CAST(ID AS CHAR(2000)) would perform a full table scan? Thank you again for all of your assistance!

Comment: I know that using CAST(ID AS CHAR(2000)) would perform a full table scan.  It was difficult to optimize our queries without any changes in the architecture of the data warehouse. And In my case, I had to change the table structure - add some new columns and I also add some new tables.

Comment: Thank you again for all of the information! This is exactly what I needed to know. I unfortunately think I will stick with CAST(<variable> AS CHAR(2000)) to limit the number of table scans that will be necessary.